# Several host page compile full project

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, smartgwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I have a GWT application that use and have 2 host pages with 2 differents EntryPoint (gwt.xml files) which some code and most important, Database (datastore in Google App Engine) common.

The problem is that one of them makes use of several external Java libraries, including SmartGWT with its JS, meanwhile the second one use none of them. When I deploy (and compile) to Google App Engine, I need to include reference in the second entry point to SmartGWT, although it's not used. If inherits directive lacks, I get lot of compilation errors. I don't want to load SmartGWT JS files (2 MBytes) when they are not necessary, growing download from a few Kbytes to 100x times Kilobytes with SmartGWT. This second host page is a Google Chrome Extension, where light load is a strong requirement.

If I run in GAE SDK eclipse local webserver without any reference to SmartGWT in second host page, it works. But if I compile the whole project (although in first hots page references to SmartGWT remains) I get errors, related to SmartGWT absence.

Is it possible to make a separate compilation of two host pages?

Answer (score 0):

Your project appears to be burdened with a dependency of questionable value.  If your project does not make heavy use of GWT, consider rewriting your web pages to not use GWT.  In some cases a framework has more drawbacks than benefits.  That does not mean the framework itself is bad, but it may be a big sledgehammer cracking a small nut.  Your project has only two pages, so it is imaginable that making it without GWT is feasible.

Comment: The problem is that for our main application use those smartGWT dependencies, but no the chrome extension. So I want to find a way to avoid this extension compiling them.